# Размытие цвета по краям сверху и снизу в Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, google-chrome, адаптивная-верстка

При открытии сайта в браузере Chrome на телефоне под Android наблюдается размытие цвета по краям (сверху/снизу), как представлено на картинке. В данном примере верхняя горизонтальная полоса реализована через `box-shadow`, нижняя вертикальная `border`. Проблема в том, что на стыке с другим блоком при просмотре с телефона будет видна полупиксельная светлая полоска, что портит дизайн. На ПК такого рендера нет. Как можно решить проблему? Или где почитать?

[image: blur in android chrome]

Собственно, в коде размытие не предусмотрено:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0px #1d5399;
```

и

```
border-left: 2px solid #1d5399;
```

Comment: `-2px` заменить на `-1.5px`?

Comment: @Qwertiy к сожалению, в моём случае не помогает